# Presto: Aggregate the arrays for all columns

Tags: sql, arrays, distinct, presto, trino

I have the following table:

```
name   pets
Alex   [dog, cat, bird]
Tom    [rabbit, cat]
Mary   [snake, dog, fish, cow]
Dave   [dog]
```

I am wondering would it be possible to create a query to find all pets. That is, I am looking for the output like:

```
[dog, cat, bird, rabbit, snake, fish, cow]
```

Current approaches is export the table to csv and use python to solve it. I am wondering if this can be done directly in Presto query? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presto has powerful array functions. This should work:

```
select array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(pets))) all_pets
from mytable
```

Basically this aggregates all arrays to together, as an array of arrays, then concatenates all elements together in a single array, and finally removes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @GMB answer, this can be more friendly from scalability perspective:

```
presto> SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT e)
     -> FROM (VALUES ARRAY[1,2,3], ARRAY[2,3,4]) t(a)
     -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST(a) AS u(e);
    _col0
--------------
 [3, 2, 4, 1]
```

This is a definitely more verbose version of `array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(pets)))`, but avoids instantiating array-or-arrays in memory.

(Ideally the Presto optimizer should be able to convert one to the other, but it is not the case yet.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT set_union(pets) as all_pets from tbl_pets
```

This should give the same result